# Compatibilization of Android TV application for Google Play (Xiaomi MiBox)

Tags: android, google-play, television, xiaomi

I have uploaded an Android TV app (minSdk = 21, compileSdk and targetSdk = 28) into Google Play. I already set the Category LEANBACK_LAUNCHER to my MainActivity and also applied successfully for Android TV App ("Price and distribution" section) on the Google Play Developer Console.

However, when searching for available Android TV devices I realized that  it works on all the Android TV devices appearing on the console but my Xiaomi MiBox3 and Xiaomi MiBox4 are still not compatible with the application. On the Google Play Developer Console I am not able to find the "MiBox3" and "MiBox4" devices even when I research for all devices (however, I can see other Xiaomi MiBox devices like "MiBox3S" or "MiBox S" and they are compatible).They do not even appear in the device catalog of Google Play Developer Console (Release Management - Device Catalog - All Devices).

Why these two devices do not appear in the Google Play Console and when I try to search & install the application it says that is not compatible with them? Is any way to include them and have them support to be installed throught Google Play?

Comment: what is your  `minSdkVersion` in your gradle ?

Comment: minSdkVersion = 21, but it should not be a problem since MiBox3 has Android 6.0.1 and MiBox4 has 8.1, right?

Comment: yes it should work

Comment: My main concern is that they do not even appear in the device catalog of the google play developer console (Release Management - Device Catalog - All Devices). Why??? Instead it appears "MiBox3S" or "MiBox S"

Comment: I have the same issue, the device is very well integrated with Google services and the Play Store, still for some reason, the app is not compatible.

Comment: It's pretty strange. You can try clearing cache and data from PlayStore app, but I finally ended up not requiring leanback at all (<uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="false" />) and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible these devices are not certified? Google Play Console only [lists certified devices](https://www.android.com/certified/) because these are the only devices with Google Play allowed on them, as they have been tested to work.

Comment: Yes, it seems like that, the certified device is the Xiaomi MiBox S (using the weblink provided). However, even if the devices are not certified, they should be able to install the application or this is not true?

Comment: If the device isn't certified, it shouldn't have Google Play on it, as this is only legally allowed on certified devices. So they won't be able to install it from Play, as Play won't be on the device. Of course, the situation does occur that people sideload Play, but then there are no guarantees about what will happen